# Return wild on zero in SQL Select

Tags: php, mysql

I've got an SQL query. I use a PHP function to run it and there are two PHP variables in there. Sometimes one of the PHP variables will be zero which will generate no results. There a way to adjust it so that if that variable is zero, it will return all records based on the other condition?

```
SELECT
          `author`.name,
          `author`.id,
          `category`.name as cat_name
        FROM
          `post`
          INNER JOIN `author` ON (`author`.id = `post`.author)
          INNER JOIN `category` ON (`category`.id = `post`.category_id)
        WHERE `author`.site_id='".$site_id."' AND `post`.category_id='".$category_id."'
            AND `category`.id <> 0
        GROUP BY `post`.author
```

What I want is to return all records where author.site_id is equal to $site_id when $category_id is equal to zero.

Comment: Just build the condition in your PHP code by adding `AND post.category_id='".$category_id."'` only if `$category_id` is not 0.

Comment: Replace `AND post.category_id='".$category_id."'` with `($category_id!=0?"AND post.category_id='".$category_id."':"")`

Comment: The SQL statement is as a variable $sql="STATEMENT". Does that change the code I need to replace apokryfos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
WHERE (`author`.site_id = '".$site_id."' OR $site_id = 0) AND
      (`post`.category_id = '".$category_id."' OR $category_id = 0) AND
      `category`.id <> 0
```

More typically, `NULL` is used for a missing value rather than `0`.  The same idea works with `NULL` . . . you just have to use `IS NULL` instead of `= 0`.

Comment: I tried that out, it did work until I tried it on the page where $category_id hadn't been set. When I echo out the SQL it put the value of $category_id in the second line where we check if it's 0.
So you can get it ending with 'OR 382=0' or 'OR 0=0' and of course the problem I'm getting is with it ending in 'OR =0'.
Is there any way round that?

Comment: You can use the NULL coalescing operator (`??`) to replace it with `0`.

Comment: I've put single quotes round $category_id. That seems to work. Could this cause any issues?

Comment: @RichardYoung . . . Only if the value contains single quotes.  You should write the query to use parameters, if these values are supplied by users or outside your control.  This is a best practice to avoid SQL injection attacks.